# Use .Net dll in silverlight

Tags: .net, dll, silverlight-4.0

I have a webservice DLL. written in .Net 2
Now I want to access methods of this dll in my Silverlight app. Is it possible as of today to access .net dll from within silverlight app? I do not have source code for my dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot referene a non-silverlight assembly from silverlight, but you can reference a silverlight assembly from a regular .net application.

Sounds like you just want to call a web service from your silverlight application.  If that is the cause you should be able to just add a web reference to your web service, so you shouldn't need to reference that dll at all I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use a .net compiled dll in silverlight. For accessing directly with silverlight, it has to be built with ".net silverlight runtime".

Silverlight is a minified version of the .net framework.

Answer (score 1):

If it is already a webservice then call the webservice methods from your silver light application

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [Reusing .NET Assemblies in Silverlight](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to to call the webservice from Silverlight.  Do you have it setup in IIS already?

Comment: webservice around webservice this sounds nice. Is there any tutorials out there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you already had a web service built.  I updated my answer.